# How do I set the session timeout with Pac4j / Shiro?

Tags: shiro, pac4j

I have a simple question:
How do I set the session timeout? Currently it seems my session is expired after max. 60 minutes, but I thout I have defined it for 10 hours...

in my shiro.ini I have this:

```
sessionManager =org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie =$sessionIdCookie
sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled =true
securityManager.sessionManager= $sessionManager

# 3,600,000 milliseconds = 1 hour -> set to 10 hours
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 36000000
```

In Keycloak I have this:
[image]

And is there anything to defined also in the web.xml, like:

```
<!-- sets the default session timeout to 480 minutes. -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>480</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pac4j `ShiroSessionStore` relies on the Shiro session: `SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession(createSession)` so it should expire as defined. Turn on `DEBUG` logs on `org.pac4j` to see what's going on.